# App name is unavailable after removing it from one account while in beta in AppStoreConnect then trying to use it in another account

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

**I have the answer for this question and got it directly from Apple.** Everything is described in the emails.

I spent several hours on this issue on the projects themselves, AppStoreConnect, Stack Overflow, blogs, and eventually contacted Apple Support. The rep was on the phone with me for at least 30 min and he was just as baffled.

The rep initially said I should push the apps for approval and then removing them to free up the name would be easy by transferring them. I said that the approval process itself could take long because i could easily get rejected and then have to resubmit, rejected resubmit... It could easily take a week to get accepted (assuming there were rejections) for all 3 apps and to go through that only for a name change didn't make any sense. He agreed that that wasn't a viable option.  He went and asked a supervisor for help and what the supervisor suggested didn't work.

He had to send the issue further up the ladder to tech support and it took them a couple of days to get back to me about what was causing the problem. It turned out to be a very simple fix that everyone initially overlooked.

So obviously this was a laborious process and I'm only posting this as a question to help the next person. There isn't any code to post but I know people have had similar issues. I'll post the answer in about an hour or so.

Again:
**I have the answer for this question and got it directly from Apple. I'm only posting this to help the next dev.**.

This is what the App rep sent me after I got off the phone with him.

> Hello Lance,
>
> This is Sunny with Apple Developer Program Support. Thank you for
>   taking the time to speak with me today.
>
> As we spoke about over the phone, I have included some information
>   below for you to fill out in regard to your issue. Please fill it out
>   to the best of your knowledge and we can then be able to further
>   research your issue. If you have extra screenshots that you would like
>   to provide, please be sure to add those as well.
>
> - Content name
> - Content Apple ID
> - Steps to reproduce the issue
> - Approximate date and time of the most recent occurrence of the issue (including the time zone)
> - Full-window screenshots or video illustrating the issue
> - Username of each user experiencing the issue
> - Web browsers that can reproduce the issue
> - Web browser version numbers
>
> Please let me know if you have any further questions. You can also
>   contact us using the link:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/contact/
>
> When contacting us, please reference your case number xxxxx.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Sunny, Apple Inc.

My response that describes the issue:

> Hello Sunny,
>
> The below issues started Sunday morning Sept 8 at 8m until the time of
>   our phone call Eastern Standard Time.
>
> Browsers;
>
> -Google Chrome Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)
>
> -Safari Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9)
>
> -Firefox Quantum 69.0 (64-bit)
>
> Under the AppleId **abc@email.com** I had 3 apps named:
>
> **-AppOne bundleId: com.oldCompany.appOne**
>
> **-AppTwo bundleId: com.oldCompany.appTwo**
>
> **-AppThree bundleId: com.oldCompany.appThree**
>
> I removed them from the AppStore connect then went to my other account
>   **xyz@email.com** > Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles > Identifiers
>   and tried to register the names with a different bundleId:
>
> **-AppOne bundleId: com.newCompany.appOne**
>
> **-AppTwo bundleId: com.newCompany.appTwo**
>
> **-AppThree bundleId: com.newCompany.appThree**
>
> I kept getting an error message:
>
> *An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
>   Identifier 'com.newCompany.appOne' is not available. Please enter a
>   different string.*
>
> *An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
>   Identifier 'com.newCompany.appTwo' is not available. Please enter a
>   different string.*
>
> *An attribute in the provided entity has invalid value An App ID with
>   Identifier 'com.newCompany.appThree' is not available. Please enter a
>   different string.*
>
> I then went back to AppStore Connect under the **abc@email.com** account,
>   restored each app, went to the localizable field and renamed all 3 of
>   them, then removed them again:
>
> (the Apple supervisor suggested renaming the names under the
>   localizable field and said that might fix the issue because the names
>   themselves might be stuck under the old account even though I removed
>   them)
>
> **-App-123 bundleId: com.oldCompany.appOne**
>
> **-App-456 bundleId: com.oldCompany.appTwo**
>
> **-App-789 bundleId: com.oldCompany.appThree**
>
> When I logged back into developer.apple as **xyz@email.co**m and tried to
>   register the names:
>
> **-AppOne bundleId: com.newCompany.appOne**
>
> **-AppTwo bundleId: com.newCompany.appTwo**
>
> **-AppThree bundleId: com.newCompany.appThree**
>
> The same errors occurred.
>
> How can I use the names **AppOne**, **AppTwo**, and **AppThree** with the **xyz@email.com**
>   account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was when I had the abc@email.com account in Apple, the bundleIds

```
com.newCompany.appOne
com.newCompany.appTwo
com.newCompany.appThree
```

were all registered there in addition to the bundleIds

```
com.oldCompany.appOne
com.oldCompany.appTwo
com.oldCompany.appThree
```

The `com.oldCompany...` bundleIds were the ones I initially had in AppStoreConnect and then removed the app. Even though the app was removed, the bundleIds were still sitting in the **abc@email.com** account so the names weren't available.

When I was trying to upload them to the new **xyz@email.com** account it kept throwing the *An attribute in the provided entity has invalid...* error.

As you can see from their response below all I had to do was delete them from the **abc@email.com** account and after that the problem was resolved.

To make a long story short if you have 2 different developer accounts make sure the bundleIds in one aren't the same bundleIds you're trying to upload to the other. It was a simple mistake that even the rep and supervisor overlooked so it can definitely happen to anyone.

**And NO if your app is in beta you DON'T need to get the app approved first to remove its name from AppStoreConnect. Removing a beta app to free up a name is fine**

Here's their response:

> Hello Lance,  Thank you for your patience while we research the error
>   you are receiving. I hope that you are enjoying your week, so far.
>
> We
>   were able to locate the reason for the error you are receiving, as
>   well as a simple fix for it. There are three App IDs that you
>   mentioned, you are unable to register to the new account. The App IDs
>   are listed below:
>
> com.newCompany.appOne
>
> com.newCompany.appTwo
>
> com.newCompany.appThree
>
> All three of these are registered on the
>   account, abc@email.com. If I am understanding correctly, they are
>   intended to be added to the account, xyx@email.com.
>
> You will first
>   need to remove the App IDs, from within Certificates, Identifiers, and
>   provisioning profiles, on the abc@email.com team. More information,
>   and instructions can be located here.
>
> https://help.apple.com/developer-account/#/devf7577d411
>
> Let me know if
>   you have any questions or need further assistance. I'm happy to help.
>   The fastest way to reach me is to respond directly to this email. I am
>   also reachable at:
>   +1 877-555-0690 ext xxxxx Monday to Friday, 7am - 4pm PST When contacting me, please note this line goes directly to my voicemail
>   only. When leaving a message, please reference your case number xxxxxx
>   and I'll get back to you as soon as I can. Best regards, Austin Apple
>   Inc.